# Parsing CSV Data to Javascript via PHP - Script Clean-Up and How to Include Only Specific Rows - Speed Testing and Display Data w/ Chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, csv, charts, chart.js

I'm a novice in PHP and am currently working on a simple project to help me learn more. I've been able to sort through many threads on Stack Overflow and pull together tidbits to achieve the basic functionality I desired, but the script it terribly clunky. As part of the learning experience, I'm hoping y'all may be able to assist me in cleaning it up / simplifying it. After much tinkering, this was the best I was able to come up with and I'd love to see how experienced programmers would handle the task.

My goal was to poll Speedtest.net each hour via a bash script scheduled in cron, write the results to a CSV file, then have the most recent 12 hours of data displayed on a web page via a chart.js rendering. I was able to accomplish the task of polling Speedtest and writing the results to a CSV file by modifying a bash script written by aallan on github (`https://gist.github.com/aallan/bafc70a347f3b9526d30`). The modified script pulls the output of speedtest-cli (`https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli`), cleans it up, and writes it to a CSV along with a time stamp; the format is timestamp,ping,download,upload. Here is an example of my current dataset living in data.csv:

```
09/22/17 00:14 CST,15.532,88.51,83.14
09/22/17 00:15 CST,15.613,92.56,96.42
09/22/17 00:16 CST,15.353,91.83,92.79
09/22/17 00:17 CST,16.766,92.52,97.28
09/22/17 00:18 CST,16.039,91.06,97.83
09/22/17 00:19 CST,5.986,89.66,94.81
09/22/17 00:20 CST,14.81,88.28,96.56
09/22/17 00:21 CST,15.24,91.54,96.10
09/22/17 00:22 CST,14.686,93.78,91.92
09/22/17 00:23 CST,5.958,73.74,66.33
09/22/17 00:24 CST,6.009,93.69,92.35
09/22/17 00:25 CST,5.895,93.20,89.96
09/22/17 00:26 CST,14.725,86.63,96.05
09/22/17 00:27 CST,5.872,93.11,91.70
09/22/17 00:28 CST,15.633,86.04,92.03
09/22/17 00:29 CST,15.144,92.55,94.58
09/22/17 00:30 CST,14.774,92.60,93.61
09/22/17 00:31 CST,5.752,91.52,92.49
09/22/17 00:32 CST,15.489,86.79,93.18
09/22/17 00:33 CST,15.572,88.81,92.04
09/22/17 00:34 CST,15.574,87.89,88.87
09/22/17 00:35 CST,15.51,88.11,88.27
09/22/17 00:36 CST,16.071,85.99,96.71
09/22/17 00:37 CST,15.502,91.26,96.28
09/22/17 00:38 CST,14.368,93.16,92.66
09/22/17 00:39 CST,16.348,91.40,93.35
09/22/17 00:40 CST,14.557,91.32,93.83
09/22/17 00:41 CST,15.722,85.99,89.33
```

Just in case anyone in the future may be embarking on a similar project, here is how I modified the last four lines of aallan's script to achieve the above result; you'll also need to have speedtest-cli available for the script to function.

```
json="${value1},${value2},${value3}"
echo -n `date +"%D %H:%M"` >> /var/www/html/data.csv
echo -n " CST," >> /var/www/html/data.csv
echo "${json}" >> /var/www/html/data.csv
```

Once I had the dataset piece sorted out, I spent a lot of time researching how to use PHP to pull out specific data from the CSV file and pass it to a JavaScript variable in order to display in webpage using chart.js. I have four variables to work with - time stamp, ping time, download speed, and upload speed. I used a few examples I found on Stack Overflow to pull the data in each column into comma separated values and then echo it into the JavaScript which drives the chart.js on the webpage; it's not pretty, but it worked. I went ahead and included the entire file in case it's helpful to someone in the future:

```
<?php
echo 'var timestamps = [';
 if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $datestamp = array(0);
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
       if (!in_array($c,$datestamp)) continue;
    {
           $datestamp_values = $data[$c];
           echo '\''.$datestamp_values.'\',';
       }
    }
   }
    fclose($handle);
 }
echo "];";
 ?>

<?php
echo 'var ping_values = [';
  if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $ping = array(1);
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
       if (!in_array($c,$ping)) continue;
    {
           $ping_values = $data[$c];
           echo ''.$ping_values.',';
       }
    }
   }
    fclose($handle);
 }
echo "];";
 ?>

<?php
echo 'var download_values = [';
 if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $download = array(2);
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
       if (!in_array($c,$download)) continue;
    {
           $download_values = $data[$c];
           echo ''.$download_values.',';
       }
    }
   }
    fclose($handle);
 }
echo "];";
 ?>

<?php
echo 'var upload_values = [';
 if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $upload = array(3);
      while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {   
       if (!in_array($c,$upload)) continue;
    {
           $upload_values = $data[$c];
           echo ''.$upload_values.',';
       }
    }
   }
    fclose($handle);
 }
echo "];";
 ?>

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: timestamps,
    datasets: [
      { 
        data: ping_values,
        label: "Ping Time",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      },
      { 
        data: download_values,
        label: "Download Speed",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      },
      { 
        data: upload_values,
        label: "Upload Speed",
        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

The file, script.php, is then called from a simple HTML page. The chart.js example I worked from to build this is located here: http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/introduction-to-chartjs/

Here is what the result of the above script looks like (PHP-driven portion anyway):

```
var timestamps = ['09/22/17 00:14 CST','09/22/17 00:15 CST','09/22/17 00:16 CST','09/22/17 00:17 CST','09/22/17 00:18 CST','09/22/17 00:19 CST','09/22/17 00:20 CST','09/22/17 00:21 CST','09/22/17 00:22 CST','09/22/17 00:23 CST','09/22/17 00:24 CST','09/22/17 00:25 CST','09/22/17 00:26 CST','09/22/17 00:27 CST','09/22/17 00:28 CST','09/22/17 00:29 CST','09/22/17 00:30 CST','09/22/17 00:31 CST','09/22/17 00:32 CST','09/22/17 00:33 CST','09/22/17 00:34 CST','09/22/17 00:35 CST','09/22/17 00:36 CST','09/22/17 00:37 CST','09/22/17 00:38 CST','09/22/17 00:39 CST','09/22/17 00:40 CST','09/22/17 00:41 CST',];
var ping_values = [15.532,15.613,15.353,16.766,16.039,5.986,14.81,15.24,14.686,5.958,6.009,5.895,14.725,5.872,15.633,15.144,14.774,5.752,15.489,15.572,15.574,15.51,16.071,15.502,14.368,16.348,14.557,15.722,];
var download_values = [88.51,92.56,91.83,92.52,91.06,89.66,88.28,91.54,93.78,73.74,93.69,93.20,86.63,93.11,86.04,92.55,92.60,91.52,86.79,88.81,87.89,88.11,85.99,91.26,93.16,91.40,91.32,85.99,];
var upload_values = [83.14,96.42,92.79,97.28,97.83,94.81,96.56,96.10,91.92,66.33,92.35,89.96,96.05,91.70,92.03,94.58,93.61,92.49,93.18,92.04,88.87,88.27,96.71,96.28,92.66,93.35,93.83,89.33,];
```

Finally, here is what the final product looks like currently:

[Like to Screenshot of Chart.js Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ULqN.png)

So it works, but it's not too pretty. How could this be cleaned up? I'd also like to find a way to only include the 12 bottom rows when the data is parsed from the CSV file - that is, the 12 most recent speedtest results would be displayed on the webpage. Any feedback on how to better format or "pretty up" the chart.js configuration would also be welcome - I wasn't able to figure out how to get the date/time stamps to text wrap and will probably end up moving the ping time results to a separate chart.

Thank you in advance for your feedback on this project and for all the learning opportunities I've found here. Cheers!

Comment: _"So it works, but it's not too pretty."_ - this sounds like it might be a better fit for code review. _" How could this be cleaned up?"_ is kind of a broad question for SO.

Comment: Just my opinion. Very thorough and nicely formatted question though!

Comment: @Chris Here's a shorter way: https://pastebin.com/VDGSZ8GT (I once spent hours manually composing JSON from lots of db query results, then I learned about `json_encode` :) Moving forward, I'd 1) store the speedtest results in a database 2) use PHP to run a query for the last 12 rows and create JSON 3) use `$.getJSON()` to load the data